# how to solve error read ECONNRESET bull library

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, queue, bull

i got error when i queue with [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) library in node js, the error is like this :

```
     Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead 
    - - errno: -104,
   - - code: 'ECONNRESET',
   - - syscall: 'read'
   - - }
```

and

```
 MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
```

this my code :

```
const imageQueue = new Bull("imageQueue", process.env.REDIS_URL);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

error solved successfully by adding tls

```
const imageQueue = new Bull("imageQueue", process.env.REDIS_TLS_URL, {
  redis: { tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bull uses ioredis to connect, and allows a third opts parameter in the Queue constructor. According to the [source code it looks for a redis property within those opts](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/lib/queue.js#L121).

You might try this to [raise the retry limit to 100](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#user-content-auto-reconnect).

```js
const opts = {redis:{maxRetriesPerRequest:100}}
const imageQueue = new Bull("imageQueue", process.env.REDIS_URL, opts);
```

But, also, you may be using Heroku's redis service more intensively than they allow for the free tier (if that's what you use).

Comment: thank you for answering, currently there is still an **ECONNRESET** error.

for your information on my local computer it works, error only when connected redis heroku.

Comment: Aha, in that case you're probably exceeding Heroku's redis-service limits. I think they charge hour-by-hour, so you could provision a more expensive plan and see if it works better for you. That would test my hypothesis of exceeding their limits.

Comment: my plan has Premium 0, is it still lacking?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar as what is suggested on the npm package docs.

```
  // This is the default value of `retryStrategy`
  retryStrategy(times) {
    const delay = Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
    return delay;
  },
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#user-content-auto-reconnect

You'd need to send this redis configuration when creating the bull queue.