# Bull (redis) process stops consuming new messages in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis, bull, bullmq

I'm initialising bull's process at the start of my worker (running via docker and k8s), and it continues to listen to the message against the configured queue (`redis` broker). Problem is, I have noticed that after some time (few hours, it's not some fix time), bull stops consuming new message, even though jobs do exists in the wait queue, I have checked in redis.
When I re-start my worker pod, it starts consuming those jobs again.
There are no errors in the 'error' event, but sometimes, I observed below error in my worker after few more hrs, not sure if it is related :

```
 at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

This is how I'm initialising bull, and activating process method

```
Worker.jobQueue = new Bull(jobName, { prefix, redis: redisOptions, enableReadyCheck: false, settings: { maxStalledCount: 30 } });

Worker.jobQueue.process(flags.concurrency, async (job) =>
        this.runJob(job),
);
...

async runJob(job: Bull.Job): Promise<IBullJobResponse> {
// some code
       return {
        success: true,
    };
}
```

Since I'm not receiving any error event, it's hard to debug this, kindly let me know what could possibly trigger this issue, it's a severe issue in my case since we are relaying on bull for all data processing, thank you.

Versions in use:

```
bull: ^4.10.2
ioredis: ^5.2.4
Nodejs: 14.15
```

Comment: I kind of facing the similar issue, in my case if service pod restarts automatically then bull stops consuming new messages but if I forcefully restart the pod then everything works fine. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @adhishspn are you using these flags while initialising bull ? if not, pls try this, it'll work and bull will try to reconnect :
maxRetriesPerRequest = null
enableReadyCheck =. false

My case is different and it's occurring on connection reset error only.

Comment: I am already using both the params, any help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839403/bull-queue-missing-process-handler-for-job-type-default is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to await the runJob handler:

```
jobQueue.process(flags.concurrency, async (job) =>
    await this.runJob(job),
);
```

To troubleshoot this issue and get more evidence consider listening and logging queue events:

```
jobQueue.on('error', function (error) {
  console.error('Job error', error);
})
.on('waiting', function (jobId) {
  console.log(`Job ${jobId} is waiting`);
})
.on('active', function (job, jobPromise) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} is active`);
})
.on('stalled', function (job) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} is stalled`);
})
.on('completed', function (job, result) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} is completed`);
})
.on('failed', function (job, err) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} is failed`);
})
.on('removed', function (job) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} is removed`);
});
```

Comment: Await didn't help. Also, none of these events caught that error immediately.
`error` event occurs after some good (around an hr). and process starts working after it, but it takes significant time.

Comment: @ShahtajK bull published more events, try adding all of them, perhaps some will catch this error https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#events

Comment: @ShahtajK what message do you see in that error event that happened after hour?

Comment: 'ECONNRESET' error, complete error is added in the question above.

Comment: @ShahtajK does some of these answers help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941211/how-to-solve-error-read-econnreset-bull-library